# Duplicate local variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently started programming with java and need help.

Using Programming Java for Dummies, I'm trying to make a game where a user has to guess a number.  The amount of attempts are recorded and displayed once the user finally gets the answer right.

The starred line is giving me trouble, any help?

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            out.println("Hello, welcome to the Guessing Game.");
            out.println("To begin, pick a random number from 1 - 10: ");

            int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
            int randomNumber = new Random(1).nextInt(10);
            int numGuesses = 0;

            while (inputNumber != randomNumber){

                out.println();
                out.println("You're guess was wrong, try again.");
                out.println("Pick an integer from 1-10.");
                **int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();** 
                numGuesses++;
            }

            {

                out.println("You won in " + numGuesses + " guesses.");

                out.println("Thanks for playing!");
            }
            }

}
```

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as "Answer" if they have solved your question

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
**int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();**
```

with

```
inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
```

With the original version, you are creating a **new variable** within the scope of the `while`, rather than assign to the old variable outside.

Since it is **destroyed after the while block**, the condition itself uses the variable in functions scope.

Answer (score 3):

This line is redeclaring inputNumber, which has already been declared.

```
int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
```

change it to

```
inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You already defined at the top so you dont have to redefine it. Instead it should be `inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();`